# WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified..Can't retrieve all files in one folder

Tags: python, directory

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-3aab1be09567>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Viji/Nlp/ResumeProject/Resume_Info_Extraction/ResumeForMyUnderstanding.py', wdir='D:/Viji/Nlp/ResumeProject/Resume_Info_Extraction')

  File "C:\Users\vijv2c13136\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\vijv2c13136\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 93, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "D:/Viji/Nlp/ResumeProject/Resume_Info_Extraction/ResumeForMyUnderstanding.py", line 394, in <module>
    p = Parse(verbose)

  File "D:/Viji/Nlp/ResumeProject/Resume_Info_Extraction/ResumeForMyUnderstanding.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.inputString = self.readFile(f)

  File "D:/Viji/Nlp/ResumeProject/Resume_Info_Extraction/ResumeForMyUnderstanding.py", line 95, in readFile
    return subprocess.Popen(['antiword', fileName], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0], extension

  File "C:\Users\vijv2c13136\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 171, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\vijv2c13136\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "C:\Users\vijv2c13136\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

def __init__(self, verbose=False):
    print('Starting Programme')
    fields = ["name", "address", "email", "phone", "mobile", "telephone", "residence status","experience","degree","cainstitute","cayear","caline","b.cominstitute","b.comyear","b.comline","icwainstitue","icwayear","icwaline","m.cominstitute","m.comyear","m.comline","mbainstitute","mbayear","mbaline","engineering","engineeringyear","engineeringline"]

    # Glob module matches certain patterns
    doc_files = glob.glob("resumes/*.doc")
    docx_files = glob.glob("resumes/*.docx")
    pdf_files = glob.glob("resumes/*.pdf")
    rtf_files = glob.glob("resumes/*.rtf")
    text_files = glob.glob("resumes/*.txt")

    files = set(doc_files + docx_files + pdf_files + rtf_files + text_files)
    files = list(files)
    print ("%d files identified" %len(files))
```

I am unable to retrieve all files in one folder, only able to retrieve one or 2 files in that directory,
Please help me out to solve this issue.
If you want, i will add my full code
Thanks in advance!!

---

Comment: Typically we see Tracebacks  formatted as code - it is easier to read.

Comment: doc_files = glob.glob("resumes/*.doc")docx_files = glob.glob("resumes/*.docx")
pdf_files = glob.glob("resumes/*.pdf")
rtf_files = glob.glob("resumes/*.rtf")
text_files = glob.glob("resumes/*.txt")

Comment: Actually, This 'resumes' folder i was facing this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Your question doesn't have enough information for anyone to help except that it appears you are lookin for a file that isn't there - see [mcve].

Comment: I added the information in your comment to the question.  If that was not what you intended, you can edit it back out.

Answer (score 0):

I was fixed my error. The .doc files is unable to retried by my code. So, i remove all the .doc files and then run my code. Now it was working correctly.